# Where can I find a radix-5 FFT implementation?

Tags: c, open-source, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to find, without success, an implementation of a radix-5 FFT. I don't need anything fancy or highly optimized, ideally a single function that performs it. A c-like language would be perfect, but any implementation would do.

Does anyone know where I could find such implementation ?

Comment: If you're feeling brave you could take a look at the FFTW source - it generates butterflies for 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 for mixed radix FFTs.

Comment: See also [this paper](http://www.briangough.com/fftalgorithms.pdf) which covers radix 5 (see equations 140 - 146).

Comment: @PaulR Thank you! I have finally been able to implement a working radix-5 (and other radix as well) using this paper! Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: Great - glad it helped ! I've converted the above comment to an answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 1997 paper by Brian Gough which covers in detail the implementation of FFTs with radix 5 (as well as other radices). The title is "FFT Algorithms" and you can get it in PDF form [here](http://www.briangough.com/fftalgorithms.pdf). See equations 140 - 146 for radix 5 implementation details.